# hover over one but affect another css

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, css-transitions

My question is simple, i did not find straight answer to it, so here: i have two boxes, i want to hover first one BUT affect second one( when hovering first one, second one should do this (transform: scale(1.2);
transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;)).
Is it possible with css or need javascript also ?
my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
display: inline-block;
margin: 30px;
font-weight: bold;
}
.a {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border : 1px solid black;
line-height: 100px;
text-align: center;
}
.c{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border : 1px solid black;
line-height: 100px;
text-align: center;
}
.d:hover {
 transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="a b">Hover me</div>

<div class="c d">Affect me</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with css, you should be able to use `+` for a direct sibling or `~` for some indirect sibling

```
.b:hover + .c {
 transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a combinator selector.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.c {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.a:hover + .d {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="a b">Hover me</div>
<div class="c d">Affect me</div>
```